# Phusion Passenger Installation Not Working

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phusion-passenger, gcc

I've been trying without success to install the Nginx version of Phusion Passenger (mod_rails) on my server by using the command `gem install passenger` followed by `passenger-install-nginx-module`.  Everything goes smoothly, until I get the below error at the end:

```
# sh ./configure --prefix='/opt/nginx' --with-http_ssl_module 
--with-pcre='/tmp/root-passenger-15796/pcre-8.10' 
--add-module='/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.6/ext/nginx'
checking for OS
 + Linux 2.6.18-028stab070.14 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... found but is not working
```

./configure: error: C compiler gcc is not found

I'm not really sure what the problem could be.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

---

**Edits from Incognito (rather than adding a million comments):**

I'm following [the guides here](http://library.linode.com/web-applications/project-management/redmine/ubuntu-11.04-natty) so that I can run redmine on nginx using postgresql. This is rigged by a shell script from `passenger-install-nginx-module` which runs

sh ./configure --prefix='/opt/nginx' --with-http_ssl_module --with-cc-opt='-Wno-error' --add-module='/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/nginx'

Right after attempting to install nginx with passenger...

Here's the relevant lines of code that throw this error: http://pastebin.com/GwrJcEkf

Here's a copy of the config.log that was spit out: http://pastebin.com/qkepYZ6X

I end up with the **exact** same issue on Ubuntu11, and Debian 6.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning, I'm following this http://library.linode.com/web-applications/project-management/redmine/ubuntu-11.04-natty so that I can run redmine on nginx using postgresql. This is trigged by a shell script from `/passenger-install-nginx-module` which runs `sh ./configure --prefix='/opt/nginx' --with-http_ssl_module --with-cc-opt='-Wno-error' --add-module='/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/nginx'` right after attempting to install nginx with passenger.

Comment: Here's the relevant lines of code that throw this error: http://pastebin.com/GwrJcEkf

Comment: Here's a copy of the config.log that was spit out: http://pastebin.com/qkepYZ6X

Answer (score 1):

`./configure: error: C compiler gcc is not found`

You don't have gcc installed and you're trying to compile something with gcc.

`sudo apt-get install gcc`

Comment: I tried that.  Gcc _is_ already installed, it's just not working.

Comment: Can I see an output of `gcc -v` and `uname -a` then? It sounds like automake can't find a working gcc compiler then... Have you ever compiled anything on this machine before?

Comment: No, I haven't; I just got it.  The output of `gcc -v` was a bunch of different "configured with" parameters, followed by `gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)`.  The output of `uname -a` was `Linux syyborg.com 2.6.18-028stab070.14 #1 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:04:02 MSK 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: So, the following command that gets called in the configure script for nginx checks to see if you have a valid gcc compiler `gcc -v 2>&1 | grep 'gcc version' 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^.* version \(.*\)/\1/'` immediately after that the line where you see `checking for C compiler ... found but is not working` is printed, can you see what running the above command in your terminal does?

Comment: better yet, compile a simple c program and see what you get--`echo 'int main(int argc, char** argv){return 1;}' > t.c; gcc -o t t.c; ./t`

Comment: The command returns `4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)`.

Comment: The second command ran with no errors.

Comment: Same results here -- No issues running GCC.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install build-essential` (sudo'ed if necessary) sorted out a similar issue for me in Debian.

Answer (score 1):

[According](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/2b67d6bec0eaf7ff/80e10074fc82d6ad) to the Hongli Lai who is author of Phusion Passenger, check to see if you have `/tmp` is mounted with `noexec` option. If not, I suggest you manual compiling from source, it would works.

Comment: Already attempted that and it was supposed to be fixed since then anyway.